# Multiply a digit array by int in C

Tags: c, arrays, multiplication

I have a very large number (>100 digits long) so it can't be stored as an `int` or even an `unsigned long long (aka uint64_t)`. The array looks like this:
`{5, 1, 2 ... 8, 6}`
The array must contain single digit `int`s.

---

**Question**

What would be a simple, and most importantly efficient, way of multiplying this 'number' (keeping it as an array) by a single digit?

**What I have tried**

As I am fairly new to C, this code is not a masterpiece. Far from it.

```c
struct returnpointer { int * pointer; int length; };

returnpointer mul_arrays(int * x, int y, int lengthof_x) {
    returnpointer result_end;
    int result[lengthof_x * 2 + 1];
    int final_result[lengthof_x * 2 + 1];
    int carry = 0;
    int j = 0;
    //multiply 'y' by all digits of x, which creates multidigit ints
    //and also reverses the direction of the array (to allow carrying)
    for (int i = lengthof_x; i >= 0; i--) {
        result[j] = x[i] * y;
        j++;
    }
    int i = 0;
    j = lengthof_x
    //this is the bit that doesn't work: it attempts to work out the carry
    //however after hours of debugging I can't get it to work.
    while (carry > 0 || i < lengthof_x + 1) {
        if (result[j] > 9) {
            carry = result[j] / 10;
            final_result[i] = result[j] % 10;
            final_result[i + 1] = carry;
        } else {
            final_result[i] = result[j];
            carry = 0;
        }
        i++;
        j--;
    }
    result_end.pointer = result;
    result_end.length  = i + 1;
    return result_end;
}
```

This code does not work properly. It is just an illustration of what I have tried (if it worked I would not be posting this).

In addition, it would be nice to know if the approach I am (trying to) use is the most efficient, as the program it will be incorporated into is very time-intensive so the faster the function the less time the entire program will take.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

My compiler is g++.

Comment: It's very difficult to say that the algorithm is most efficient, but using 3.2 bits of a 32 bit `int` is probably not the most efficient. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Fast_multiplication_algorithms_for_large_inputs

Comment: @NeilEdelman yes, very True. I am mostly focusing on processing speed and have 64 GiB RAM to play with, however.

Comment: The product can be one element longer when multiplying by a single digit. It is more efficient to store the number in little-endian sequence, and then the carry-out can be in the next element (reallocated if necessary). It's simple to do it just like you would with paper and pencil, and the function can return the same (or reallocated) pointer. You seem to have over-complicated it.

Comment: @WeatherVane could you give a code example? I don't understand how I would do that in C as I am not too familiar with it.

Comment: @NeilEdelman that sounds pretty cool however I would have no idea of how to implement that in C (see previous comment). If you could provide an example that would be very helpful.

Comment: How is the array be to read? Is `{1, 2, 3}` the number `123` or the number `321` ?

Comment: @4386427 read as 123

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested, here is a code example that multiplies an array by a single digit. The array is little-endian. For a simple example, I have assumed that the array is of fixed length, a more complex one would allocate array memory and extend it if the array grows too big.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define BIGLEN 20

typedef struct {
    int length;
    int array[BIGLEN];
} biggy_t;

void bigmul(biggy_t *big, int mul)
{
    int carry = 0, partial;
    for(int i = 0; i < big->length; i++) {
        partial = big->array[i] * mul + carry;
        big->array[i] = partial % 10;
        carry = partial / 10;
    }
    if(carry) {
        big->array[big->length] = carry;
        big->length++;
    }
}

void bigout(biggy_t *big)
{
    for(int i = big->length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        printf("%d", big->array[i]);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    biggy_t big = { 6, { 5, 1, 2, 3, 8, 6 }};   // reverse order
    bigout(&big);
    printf(" * 7 = ");

    bigmul(&big, 7);
    bigout(&big);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Program output

```
683215 * 7 = 4782505
```

I wrote a bignum implementation in which I can chose the radix. 10 or 100 for byte storage, much more for 32-bit storage. Sticking to a power of 10 makes the conversion to decimal output easier than a power of 2 radix, with a small time penalty for not using the full capacity of the storage type.

Comment: @Jachdich Notice: As Weather Vane states in the begining "The array is little-endian." That means that this code treats `{1, 2, 3}` as the number `321`. According to your comment that is not what you need. So to use this code you'll have to do some "array reverting" (or change your format to little-endian" if that's an option)

Comment: @4386427 or initialise the array from its source in this order in the first place. I presume the operand comes from a string, so find the string length and set up the `struct` from that. I didn't intend to post a complete solution, so as to leave OP something to do.

Comment: @WeatherVane True - that was exactly what I ment by: "... or change your format to little-endian" if that's an option".

Comment: @Jachdich about endianness. When using operators `+ - * /` the little-endian system is suitable, because when the number of digits grows or shrinks, you can accomodate it without having to shuffle the array. When choosing a data structure, pick what will suit the machine and the algorithm. If that's not how humans are accustomed to it, make the switch at the human/machine interface: don't be hampered by struggling to work with it. Separate **form** from **function**. Similarly in a game, say chess, you wouldn't work with the text name "Queen" etc, but with an `enum` which represents it.

Comment: @WeatherVane yeah thanks. I will consider redesigning my code to do that.

Answer (score 1):

So a few observations:

1) I don't think there is any need to reverse the array.  Just process it from least significant to most significant digit.

2) There is no reason to store temporary values larger than your allowable digit range.  Just do the carry as you go, like you would if you were doing it by hand:

```
carry = 0
for i in all_the_digits:
    product = x[i]*y + carry
    x[i] = product%10
    carry = product/10
```

3) you can store the digits as `uint8_t` without fear of overflow - this will make your array 1/4 the current size, which should improve speed due to caching effects.

Comment: Thanks, I shall translate that to C and try it in an hour or so when I get a second

Comment: This is not the fastest possible method - see the link from @Neil Edelman above - but it's a good start for understanding arbitrary size integer math.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in your code. Not sure I have spotted all of them but here is some to start with.

This loop:

```
for (int i = lengthof_x; i >= 0; i--) {
    result[j] = x[i] * y;
    j++;
}
```

execute "lengthof_x + 1" times. In other words - one time too many! You want to change it to:

```
for (int i = lengthof_x - 1; i >= 0; i--) {  // notice the "- 1"
    result[j] = x[i] * y;
    j++;
}
```

Further you have:

```
result_end.pointer = result;
```

but it seems that you have calculated the result in the variable `final_result` so you are returning the wrong array.

**However** - in any case you are **not allowed** to return a pointer to a local array! It will go out of scope when the function returns. So even if you do:

```
result_end.pointer = final_result;
```

it is still invalid code. You'll need to `malloc` the array (and that will hurt performance).

Then you have:

```
result_end.length  = i + 1;
```

So you increment the length in **all** cases. That's wrong. You should only increment when you have a carry.

Below I have tried to fix your code, i.e. I have tried to keep the overall structure of your code so that you can see where you did mistakes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct returnpointer { int * pointer; int length; };

void print_num(struct returnpointer * num)
{
        printf("len=%d\nvalue=", num->length);
    for(int i = 0; i <num->length; i++) {
        printf("%d", num->pointer[i]);
    }
}

struct returnpointer mul_arrays(int * x, int y, int lengthof_x) {
    struct returnpointer result_end;
    int result[lengthof_x + 1];

    // Multiply all element and revert array
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = lengthof_x-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        result[j] = x[i] * y;
        j++;
    }

    // Handle carry 
    int carry = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < lengthof_x; j++) {
        result[j] = result[j] + carry;
        carry = result[j] / 10;
        result[j] = result[j] % 10;
    }

    // Did length increase
    if (carry)
    {
        lengthof_x++;
        result[j] = carry;
    }

    // malloc result and revert back to desired format
    j = 0;
    int* final_result = malloc(lengthof_x * sizeof *final_result);
    for (int i = lengthof_x-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        final_result[j] = result[i];
        j++;
    }

    result_end.pointer = final_result;
    result_end.length  = lengthof_x;
    return result_end;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int arr[] = { 5, 1, 2, 3, 8, 6}; 
    struct returnpointer num = mul_arrays(arr, 2, 6);  // 512386 * 2 -> 1024772
    print_num(&num);
}
```

Output:

```
len=7
value=1024772
```

Notice however that this is **not** an optimal solution...